# Interpreting sobol indices

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, sobol-indices

I am trying to test the sensitivity of my model to a change in the parameters std and translation_factor. I get the following results :

Sobol First Order Indices:
translation_factor: -1.5191877062480437
std: -1.7561432756484356

Sobol First Order Indices confidence:
translation_factor: 0.036428989388587026
std: 0.042224152610529656

Sobol Second Order Indices:
translation_factor: [       nan 1.67631844]
std: [nan nan]

Sobol Total Order Indices:
translation_factor: 4.64711430579525
std: 6.145922074496489

Sobol Total Order Indices confidence:
translation_factor: 0.053866368603652404
std: 0.073963571700458

Could somebody please help me understand these results?
I don't understand why my first order indices are inferior to zero. Aren't they suppose to take values between zero and one?
Furthermore, for the total sobol indices can I interpret something more than std impacts more the output of my model than translation_factor ? Can I know for example if the impact of these parameters on the output is significant or not?